# Laravel / wordpress blog sharing header and footer. URL change for languages

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, wpml

We have a laravel application with a wordpress blog in it, which works fine. ( Blog is inside /public )

First, we would like to use the same header and footer as the laravel frontend in the blog without having to duplicate it (this is a partial solution we came up with, and it would be really annoying).

Second, our application is using www.domain.ext/en/blog for instance, and wordpress is gonna change that into blog/en. Is there a way to mantain our structure?

We know about Corcel, but doesn't look like it helps that much in this situation (unless the only way out is to pull posts manually, which would lead us to more problems with WPML, that Corcel doesn't support as far as we know).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked into Laravel's [blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade)? You can create a master file with the header and footer, and all of your subpages would extend the master.

Comment: We do that for our laravel views structure, but we tried to include it inside wordpress folder to no avail. It's like we can't 'see' from public folder to the views in resources folder. doesn't show anything, no errors.

Comment: what about do it the other way around, put your header/footer file in the public folder and include it in your blade files